# Set Font type for an Excel Workbook

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am taking an Excel which already has some data entered by users. I am too writing data to the same excel from my script. But i want to make sure that after the end of my operations i have a single font type used across sheets inside the excel workbook. For example i want the entire excel to have 'Arial' font. I went through previous stackoverflow solutions but it did not worked. I know we can iterate through each cell and set styles but i want to avoid that approach if possible.

I have tried the following code.

```
from openpyxl.styles import  
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook(my_path\\MyExcel.xlsx')

# performing my operations and writing data

# here at the end i want to make sure font across the workbook is Arial

DEFAULT_FONT.name = "Arial"
wb.save('my_path\\MyExcel.xlsx')
```

But this does not work any more. I tried finding some methods from different packages but i am not getting any. Please help.

Comment: Can you use Xlwings?

Comment: there is no method for such operation

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is an API for it Openpyxl does things cell by cell.

I don't know what your comment relates to, however.
If you [can] use Xlwings you can do the same things as you can with the Excel application like;

```
import xlwings as xw


xlfile = 'foo.xlsx'
with xw.App(visible=False) as app:
    wb = xw.Book(xlfile)
    ws = wb.sheets['Sheet1']

    ws['A1'].expand().font.name = 'Arial'
    ws['A1'].expand().font.size = 16

    wb.save('foo_out.xlsx')
```

This example changes all the used cells in the sheet to the same font name and size.